# where in table A but not B in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, codeigniter

i am using codeigniters sql selection to select users where not in a set of id's.

```
$this->db->select('fbuid')->where_in('fbuid', $friends);
$query   = $this->db->get('users');
```

im am trying to add another clause where it check for and not in friends table (id column). im trying to add use

```
$this->db-where_not_in
```

but i can't seem to get it to work

heres a pseudocode sql statement

```
SELECT fbuid FROM users WHERE IN () BUT NOT IN the friends TABLE ID COLUMN
```

Comment: An sql approach would be to get the ResultSet from first table and then `EXCEPT` the second ResultSet you will get from another table.

Comment: What's in $friends? another query?

Comment: an array of fbuid ids

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$query = $this->db->select('fbuid')
         ->from('users')
         ->where_in('fbuid', $friends)
         ->where_not_in('fbuid', $otherFriends);
```

**EDIT:**

You can either make a subquery before and store it in array OR do this in one step:

```
$query = $this->db->select('fbuid')
             ->from('users')
             ->where_in('fbuid', $friends)
             ->where('`fbuid` NOT IN (SELECT `uid` FROM `another_table`)', NULL, FALSE);
```

NULL, FALSE  are important.

Comment: but          ->where_not_in('fbuid', $otherFriends);
needs to reference another table, not the users table

Comment: this another table you mentioned, does it also have fbuid field??

Comment: yes, but the column in the 'Friends' table is called UID

Comment: Did this help you at all?

Comment: no it didn't i ended up writing the sql manually instead of trying to with codeigniter funcitons